# I need to change the bottom menu color in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How to change the bottom menu color white to black in flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

final color = Colors.orange;
final myTheme = SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(systemNavigationBarColor: color);

SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(myTheme);
```